# OpenCL: single compute device on GPU?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, gpu

So I am running my OpenCL program on a GeForce GT 610. I know CUDA would be a better alternative, and I may write a CUDA version of my code later, however for know I am writing in OpenCL for the sake of also being able to run on AMD graphics cards.

During initialization I pick out a device to run on. Here is what my program prints out during this phase:

```
OpenCL Platform 0: NVIDIA CUDA
 ----- OpenCL Device # 0: GeForce GT 610-----
Gflops: 1.620000
Max Compute Units: 1
Max Clock Frequency: 1620
Total Memory of Device (bytes): 1072889856
Max Size of Memory Object Allocation (bytes): 268222464
Max Work Group Size: 1024
```

My question is why does it say the max compute unit is only 1? According to the spec details on the GeForce site, [it has 48 CUDA cores](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-610/specifications). I know that CUDA runs better on Nvidia cards, but does it really limit it this much? Nvidia limits OpenCL to 1/48th of the power?

Here is what my code the prints the following looks like:

```
if (clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[platform], CL_PLATFORM_NAME, sizeof(name), name, NULL)) Fatal("Cannot get OpenCL platform name\n");
if (verbose) printf("OpenCL Platform %d: %s\n", platform, name);
```

... inside forloop ...

```
  cl_uint compUnits, freq;
  cl_ulong memSize, maxAlloc;
  size_t maxWorkGrps;

  if (clGetDeviceInfo(id[devId], CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS, sizeof(compUnits), &compUnits, NULL)) Fatal("Cannot get OpenCL device units\n");
  if (clGetDeviceInfo(id[devId], CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY, sizeof(freq), &freq, NULL)) Fatal("Cannot get OpenCL device frequency\n");
  if (clGetDeviceInfo(id[devId], CL_DEVICE_NAME, sizeof(name), name, NULL)) Fatal("Cannot get OpenCL device name\n");

  if (clGetDeviceInfo(id[devId], CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE, sizeof(memSize), &memSize, NULL)) Fatal("Cannot get OpenCL memory size.\n");
  if (clGetDeviceInfo(id[devId], CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE, sizeof(memSize), &maxAlloc, NULL)) Fatal("Cannot get OpenCL memory size.\n");

  if (clGetDeviceInfo(id[devId], CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(maxWorkGrps), &maxWorkGrps, NULL)) Fatal("Cannot get OpenCL max work group size\n");

  int Gflops = compUnits * freq;

  if (verbose) printf(" ----- OpenCL Device # %d: %s-----\n"
    "Gflops: %f\n"
    "Max Compute Units: %d\n"
    "Max Clock Frequency: %d\n"
    "Total Memory of Device (bytes): %lu\n"
    "Max Size of Memory Object Allocation (bytes): %lu\n"
    "Max Work Group Size: %d\n",
    devId,
    name,
    1e-3*Gflops,
    compUnits,
    freq,
    memSize,
    maxAlloc,
    maxWorkGrps);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is why does it say the max compute unit is only 1?

The compute unit being referred to here corresponds to a [NVIDIA GPU SM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_(microarchitecture)) (streaming multiprocessor).  That GPU has exactly one SM, which has 48 cores inside it.

So you're not limited to a single core or 1/48th of the capability of that GPU.  Access to that compute unit means your program will have access to the 48 cores contained in it.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you. How would I go about finding out exactly how many threads I can have running in parallel on this device?

Comment: You can launch an OpenCL kernel that uses many threads (work items).  The GPU will process them at whatever rate it is able.  The instantaneous capacity of the GPU is specified (e.g. 1536 work items can be resident per Fermi SM) but this does *not* mean you should think about writing programs that use 1536 work items for the global size (or the local size, for that matter).  Use as large of a work structure as makes sense for your problem.  Don't bother with worrying about the 1536 number in this case.